# request.user returning AnonymousUser in ModelViewSet, but working properly in APIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to customize get_queryset() in my DocumentViewSet so the GET method will return all Document objects created by request.user (currently logged in user).

However, I am stuck in this error:`django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“AnonymousUser” is not a valid UUID.']`

I assume this is caused by getting AnonymousUser as my self.request.user. The weird part is that my other APIView that deals with request.user are working flawlessly; The only difference I could find between the two is type of viewset: ModelViewSet vs APIView.

Would appreciate any help!

#### document.views

```
class DocumentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Document
    serializer_class = DocumentSerializer
    list_serializer_class = DocumentListSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Document.objects.filter(user=user)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == "list":
            if hasattr(self, "list_serializer_class"):
                return self.list_serializer_class

        return super(DocumentViewSet, self).get_serializer_class()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        print(self.request.user)
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

#### document.serializers

```
class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = HashidSerializerCharField(source_field="documents.Document.id", read_only=True)
    question_blocks = QuestionBlockSerializer(many=True)
    outline_blocks = OutlineBlockSerializer(many=True)
    source_cards = SourceSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        question_blocks = validated_data.pop("question_blocks")
        outline_blocks = validated_data.pop("outline_blocks")
        source_cards = validated_data.pop("source_cards")
        document = Document.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for qBlock in question_blocks:
            QuestionBlock.objects.create(document=document, **qBlock)
        for oBlock in outline_blocks:
            OutlineBlock.objects.create(document=document, **oBlock)
        for sCard in source_cards:
            Source.objects.create(document=document, **sCard)
        document.save()
        return document


class DocumentListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = HashidSerializerCharField(source_field="documents.Document.id", read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ("id", "title", "template", "updated")
```

#### document.models

```
class Document(models.Model):
    id = HashidAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Untitled")
    template = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    editorState = models.JSONField(default=[])
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

#### user.models

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    username = None
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="unknown")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="unknown")
    profile_pic = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="unknown")

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, db_index=True)
    secret_key = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=get_random_secret_key)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        swappable = "AUTH_USER_MODEL"
```

### users.api & selectors

This is the APIView which returns information of the user currently logged-in; It is working flawlessly.

```
# users.api

class UserMeApi(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(user_get_me(user=request.user))

# users.selectors

def user_get_me(*, user: User):
    return {
        "id": user.id,
        "name": user.name,
        "email": user.email,
        "first_name": user.first_name,
        "last_name": user.last_name,
        "profile_pic": user.profile_pic,
    }
```

**EDIT**: added document.serializer and rest of the viewset code

Comment: Change `AllowAny` to [`IsAuthenticated`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticated)

Comment: @JPG I've tried that before and is still returning the same error. I just put AllowAny for testing

Comment: Are there any other overridden function in DocumentViewSet?

Comment: @FrançoisFournier Just edited my post with the code I didn't include before. I have a "list serializer" which only returns limited fields in GET view, and this list view is where I wish to implement "return list of documents created by request.user"

Answer (score 0):

My mistake! The origin of the problem was on the frontend; I forgot to include **withCredentials:true** in axios GET request.

```
axios
  .get<DocumentList>(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/drafts/?format=json`,
    {
      withCredentials: true, //forgot this part!
    }
  )
  .then(function (response) {
    setDrafts(response.data.results);
  });
```